# Why CUDA Command line profiler doesn't recognize some counters?

Tags: cuda, profiler

I am working remotely on some CUDA program in the Linux environment. Since there are problems with X-forwarding, I cannot use CUDA Visual Profiler and have to use CUDA Command Line profiler instead.

The problem is, it doesn't recognize some basic counters I want it to follow. E.g running the program with the following command

```
COMPUTE_PROFILE=1 COMPUTE_PROFILE_CSV=0 COMPUTE_PROFILE_LOG=log  \
CUDA_PROFILE_CONFIG=Config.txt ./my_program
```

With the Config.txt file being:

```
warp_serialize
shared_replay_overhead
```

Results in the following log:

```
NV_Warning: Ignoring the invalid profiler config option: warp_serialize
NV_Warning: Ignoring the invalid profiler config option: shared_replay_overhead
CUDA_PROFILE_LOG_VERSION 2.0
CUDA_DEVICE 0 GeForce GTX 580
CUDA_CONTEXT 1
TIMESTAMPFACTOR fffff6c8b2653dd8
```

...

My enviroment specifications:

```
Card: GeForce GTX 580
CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version:          4.1 / 4.1
CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.0
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `warp_serialize` counter **is not supported** for devices of **compute capability 2.x**. See Table 6. Profiler Counter Types at Compute Visual Profiler User guide.

Regarding to the `shared_replay_overhead` I have not found anything related to it.